# Prove $f(x) \to \beta$ as $x \to \beta$ using squeeze theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The question is:

> Use the definition to show that $|x - \beta| \to 0$ as $x \to \beta$. A function is defined on an open interval which contains $\beta$ and, for each $x$ in this interval, $f(x)$ lies between $\beta$ and $x$. Prove $f(x) \to  \beta$ as $x \to \beta$.

here is my take:

for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ so that $|x-\beta| < \epsilon$ provided with $0 < |x-\beta| < \delta$ and we take $\epsilon = \delta$... this is the farthest I could get using the definition of $\epsilon, \delta$. I feel like I could use squeeze(sandwich) theorem at some point, but I don't how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ is sandwiched between $\beta + (x-\beta)$ and $\beta - (x-\beta)$. Both functions $\to \beta$ as $x \to \beta$, so...

Comment: how did you observe that $|f(x)-\beta| \le |\beta-x|$??

Comment: @Allie It says $x < f(x) < \beta$. (Reverse the sign when necessary)

Comment: doesnt it $0 < |x-\beta| < \delta$ instead? not x?

Comment: @Allie That is the condition on $x$, since $|f(x) - \beta| \leq |beta - x|$ only holds in an open interval.

Comment: OK. I was just confused about how $|f(x)-\beta| \le |\beta-x|$ holds.. becasue both $|x-\beta-0| < \epsilon$ $|f(x)-\beta| < \epsilon|$ holds.

Comment: @Allie It is $|x - \beta| < \epsilon \implies |f(x) - \beta| < \epsilon$.

Comment: but how does $|x-\beta| < \epsilon$ bigger than $|f(x)-\beta|$?? that's the part i find it confusing.. is that just an OBVIOUS thing but im just too dumb to realize?

Comment: FINISHING THIS PROOF i say
>for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ so that $|x-\beta| < \epsilon$ provided with $0 < |x-\beta| < \delta$ and we take $\epsilon = \delta$ and since $f(x) \to \beta$ as $x \to \beta$ we can say, $|f(x)-\beta| < \epsilon$ with $x<|x-\beta| < \delta$ and it's $x$, not $0$ because its open interval. then I say that eqaulity holds, thus by squeeze this works?

Comment: @Allie You only need to show that both bounds converge to the same value. Squeeze theorem will take care of the rest.